# DirectorySearcher - Clauses and keywords for search

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am very new to working with Active Directory. After spending some time on web I was able to get code for getting users from active directory using the `DirectorySearcher` class. However I am facing hard time in getting a list of all supported clauses and keywords of search.

The only link I was able to get is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475(v=vs.85).aspx. But got only few keywords.

Kindly share links / list of keywords and clauses. Below are some I found;

1. `&(objectClass=user)`
2. `(objectCategory=person)`
3. `(manager=...)`
4. `(!msExchResourceMetaData=ResourceType:Room)`
5. `(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))`

Also I tried creating a org chart using MS. Visio and then with `DirectorySearcher` code. The Visio files excludes virtual accounts such as feedback@abc.com, meeting rooms, etc. but my Directory searcher code gets them.

Kindly help.

Comment: Are you asking to rewrite [RFC2254](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2254.txt) for you as *ADSI supports the LDAP search filters as defined in RFC2254*?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using .NET 3.5 or newer, then you can use a `PrincipalSearcher` and a "query-by-example" principal to do your searching much more simply than with the "low-level" `DirectorySearcher`:

```
// create your domain context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
   // define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a UserPrincipal 
   // and with the first name (GivenName) of "Bruce" and a last name (Surname) of "Miller"
   UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
   qbeUser.GivenName = "Bruce";
   qbeUser.Surname = "Miller";

   // create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
   PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

   // find all matches
   foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
   {
       // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal" - it could be user, group, computer.....          
   }
}
```

If you haven't already - absolutely read the MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5 (MSDN Mag, Jan 2008 issue)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/A/7/3A7FA450-1F33-41F7-9E6D-3AA95B5A6AEA/MSDNMagazineJanuary2008en-us.chm) which shows nicely how to make the best use of the new features in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`. Or see the [MSDN documentation on the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx) namespace.

Of course, depending on your need, you might want to specify other properties on that "query-by-example" user principal you create:

- `DisplayName` (typically: first name + space + last name)
- `SAM Account Name` - your Windows/AD account name
- `User Principal Name` - your "username@yourcompany.com" style name

You can specify any of the properties on the `UserPrincipal` and use those as "query-by-example" for your `PrincipalSearcher`.